# Google Analytics Query Builder - Issue with multiple custom dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We are trying to generate report using two custom dimension having scope "hit" but getting blank report each time. We are using the below parameter for report generation.
Metrics: ga:totalevents
Dimensions: Custom Dimension 1, Custom Dimension 2

How can we retrieve or generate report using the above parameter

Note: We are able to successfully generate report using 1 custom dimension at a time.

Comment: Are you able to get data for the same query in Analytics UI, if you build a custom report? (I.e., is there any valid data in Analytics?)

Comment: We are trying to capture multiple information for each "hit" on the site - user name, user group information, link that is being clicked etc. We are storing all this information in individual custom dimension. and each are showing result if we are pulling individual report. The results are not returned when we are trying to get all the custom dimension in single report

Comment: could you please add code of your request and sample response?

Comment: gtag("config", "tracking-id", { custom_map: { dimension27: 'dimension name' } });
gtag('event', 'Document Source', { 'dimension name': `Value` });